# Doing real-time calculations in a form in react js components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a new user to React and I'm having trouble with my app.. Basically I want to do some calculation when the user input some values it dynamically outputs the amount. The calculation should add the packaging amt with transport amt and subtract the discount amt, the result is then added to the product of kgs with price per kg to show the total amt.  . If anyone can help me with this it would be very much appreciated. My code is included below `

```
import React from "react";
import APIHandler from "../utils/APIHandler";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AutoCompleteCustomer from "../components/AutoCompleteCustomer";

class HomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    errorRes: false,
    errorMessage: "",
    btnMessage: 0,
    sendData: false,
    farmerlist: [],
    customersDetails: [{
      phone: "",
      name: "",
    }],
    dataLoaded: false,
    value: ""
  };

  async formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ btnMessage: 1 });
    var apiHandler = new APIHandler();
    var response = await apiHandler.saveOrdersData(
      event.target.phone.value,
      event.target.id.value,
      event.target.town.value,
      event.target.region.value,
      event.target.kgs.value,
      event.target.packaging.value,
      event.target.discount.value,
      event.target.transport.value,
      event.target.comment.value,
      event.target.farmer_id.value,
      event.target.price.value,
      event.target.amount.value,
    );
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({ btnMessage: 0 });
    this.setState({ errorRes: response.data.error });
    this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.message });
    this.setState({ sendData: true });
  }

  //This Method Work When Our Page is Ready
  componentDidMount() {
    this.LoadFarmer();
  }

  async LoadFarmer() {
    var apihandler = new APIHandler();
    var farmerdata = await apihandler.fetchFarmerOnly();
    this.setState({ farmerlist: farmerdata.data });
  }

  showDataInInputs = (index, item) => {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(item);
    this.setState.customersDetails[index].phone = item.phone;
    this.setState.customersDetails[index].id = item.id;
  }

  viewRequestDetails = (request_id) => {
    console.log(request_id);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.history.push("/ordersDetails/" + request_id);
  };

  qtyChangeUpdate = (event) => {
    var value = event.target.value;
    
    this.state.total =
      ((parseInt(this.state.packaging) +
        parseInt(this.state.transport) -
        parseInt(this.state.discount)) +
      (parseInt(this.state.kgs) * parseInt(this.state.price))) * value;
    this.state.amount = value;
    this.setState({});
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <section className="content">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="block-header">
            <h2>MANAGE ORDERS & CUSTOMERS</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="row clearfix">
            <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="header">
                  <h2>Add Order</h2>
                    <ul className="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                        <Link to="/addcustomer" className="toggled waves-effect waves-block">   
                            <button className="btn btn-primary m-r-15 waves-effect">
                                Add Customer
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="body">
                  <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
                  {this.state.customersDetails.map((item, index) => (
                    <div className="row" key={index}> 
                        <div className="col-lg-6"> 
                            <label htmlFor="email_address">
                              Phone No.{" "}
                            </label>
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <div className="form-line">
                                <AutoCompleteCustomer
                                  itemPostion={index}
                                  showDataInInputs={this.showDataInInputs}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                        <div className="col-lg-6"> 
                          <label htmlFor="email_address">Customer Name</label>
                          <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="form-line">
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                id="id"
                                name="id"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter Customer Name"
                                defaultValue={item.id}
                                data-index={index}
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                  ))}
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Town</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="town"
                              name="town"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Customer Town"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    
                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Region</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <select id="region" name="region" className="form-control show-tick">
                              <option value="1">Nairobi</option>
                              <option value="2">Nyanza</option>
                              <option value="3">Central</option>
                              <option value="4">Coast</option>
                              <option value="5">Eastern</option>
                              <option value="6">North Eastern</option>
                              <option value="7">Western</option>
                              <option value="8">Rift Valley</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Kgs : </label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                              <input
                              type="text"
                              id="kgs"
                              name="kgs"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Quantity."
                              defaultValue={this.state.kgs}
                              onChange={this.qtyChangeUpdate}
                              />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Packaging</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="packaging"
                              name="packaging"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Amount"
                              defaultValue={this.state.packaging}
                              onChange={this.qtyChangeUpdate}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Discount.</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="discount"
                              name="discount"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Discount."
                              defaultValue={this.state.discount}
                              onChange={this.qtyChangeUpdate}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Transport</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="transport"
                              name="transport"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Transport."
                              defaultValue={this.state.transport}
                              onChange={this.qtyChangeUpdate}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Comment</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="comment"
                              name="comment"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Comment"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Farmer Name</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <select className="form-control show-tick"
                              id="farmer_id"
                              name="farmer_id"
                          >
                            {this.state.farmerlist.map((item) => (
                              <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                                {item.name}
                              </option>
                            ))}
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>  

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Price per Kg</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="price"
                              name="price"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Price"
                              defaultValue={this.state.price}
                              onChange={this.qtyChangeUpdate}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>  

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Amount</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="amount"
                              name="amount"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Amount"
                              value={this.state.amount}
                              onChange={this.qtyChangeUpdate}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                    
                    </div>  

                      <br />
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-success m-t-15 waves-effect "
                        disabled={this.state.btnMessage === 0 ? false : true}
                      >
                        {this.state.btnMessage === 0
                          ? "Add Order"
                          : "Adding Order Please Wait.."}
                      </button>
                      <br />
                      {this.state.errorRes === false &&
                      this.state.sendData === true ? (
                        <div className="alert alert-success">
                          <strong>Success!</strong> {this.state.errorMessage}.
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                      {this.state.errorRes === true &&
                      this.state.sendData === true ? (
                        <div className="alert alert-danger">
                          <strong>Failed!</strong>
                          {this.state.errorMessage}.
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

Comment: The only advice I can give is start using react-hooks it will make your coding so much easier - don't use class Components its old and it will make it hard for you to get help and because most developers stopped using it 2-3 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using  `setState` an binding event to the form

```
import React from "react";
import APIHandler from "../utils/APIHandler";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AutoCompleteCustomer from "../components/AutoCompleteCustomer";

class HomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);
    this.updateKgs = this.updateKgs.bind(this);
    this.updatePackaging = this.updatePackaging.bind(this);
    this.updateDiscount = this.updateDiscount.bind(this);
    this.updateTransport = this.updateTransport.bind(this);
    this.updatePrice = this.updatePrice.bind(this);
    this.formRef = React.createRef();
  }

  state = {
    errorRes: false,
    errorMessage: "",
    btnMessage: 0,
    sendData: false,
    farmerlist: [],
    kgs: "",
    price: "",
    packaging: "",
    discount: "",
    transport: "",
    amount: "",
    customersDetails: [
      {
        id: 0,
        phone: "",
        name: "",
        customer_id: "",
      },
    ],
    dataLoaded: false,
    
  };

  async formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ btnMessage: 1 });
    var apiHandler = new APIHandler();
    var response = await apiHandler.saveOrdersData(
      event.target.phone.value,
      event.target.name.value,
      event.target.customer_id.value,
      event.target.town.value,
      event.target.region.value,
      event.target.kgs.value,
      event.target.packaging.value,
      event.target.discount.value,
      event.target.transport.value,
      event.target.comment.value,
      event.target.farmer_id.value,
      event.target.rice_type.value,
      event.target.price.value,
      event.target.amount.value,
    );
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({ btnMessage: 0 });
    this.setState({ errorRes: response.data.error });
    this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.message });
    this.setState({ sendData: true });
    this.formRef.current.reset();
  }

  //This Method Work When Our Page is Ready
  componentDidMount() {
    this.LoadFarmer();
  }

  async LoadFarmer() {
    var apihandler = new APIHandler();
    var farmerdata = await apihandler.fetchFarmerOnly();
    this.setState({ farmerlist: farmerdata.data });
  }

  showDataInInputs = (index, item) => {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(item);
    this.state.customersDetails[index].id = item.id;
    this.state.customersDetails[index].phone = item.phone;
    this.state.customersDetails[index].name = item.name;
    this.state.customersDetails[index].customer_id = item.id;
    this.setState({})
  }

 updateKgs = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    kgs: event.target.value
  });
 }

 updatePackaging = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    packaging: event.target.value
  });
  console.log(this.state.packaging)
 }

 updateDiscount = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    discount: event.target.value
  });
 }

 updateTransport = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    transport: event.target.value
  });
 }

 updatePrice = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    price: event.target.value
  });
 }

 updateAmount = () => {
  this.setState({
    amount: (Number(this.state.kgs) * Number(this.state.price)) + Number(this.state.packaging) + Number(this.state.transport) - Number(this.state.discount)
    
  });  
 }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <section className="content">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="block-header">
            <h2>ADD ORDERS & CUSTOMERS</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="row clearfix">
            <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="header">
                  <h2>Add Order</h2>
                    <ul className="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                        <Link to={"/addcustomer"} className="toggled waves-effect waves-block">   
                            <button className="btn btn-primary m-r-15 waves-effect">
                                Add Customer
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="body">
                  <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit} ref={this.formRef}>
                  {this.state.customersDetails.map((item, index) => (
                    <div className="row" key={index}> 
                        <div className="col-lg-6"> 
                            <label htmlFor="email_address">
                              Phone No.{" "}
                            </label>
                            <div className="form-group">
                              <div className="form-line">
                                <AutoCompleteCustomer
                                  itemPostion={index}
                                  showDataInInputs={this.showDataInInputs}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                        <div className="col-lg-5"> 
                          <label htmlFor="email_address">Customer Name</label>
                          <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="form-line">
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                id="name"
                                name="name"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter Customer Name"
                                defaultValue={item.name}
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div> 

                        <div className="col-sm-1"> 
                          <label htmlFor="email_address">No</label>
                          <div className="form-group">
                            <div className="form-line">
                              <input
                                type="text"
                                id="customer_id"
                                name="customer_id"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder=""
                                value={item.customer_id}
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                  ))}
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Town</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="town"
                              name="town"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Customer Town"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    
                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Region</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <select id="region" name="region" className="form-control show-tick">
                              <option value="1">NAIROBI</option>
                              <option value="2">NYANZA</option>
                              <option value="3">CENTRAL</option>
                              <option value="4">COAST</option>
                              <option value="5">EASTERN</option>
                              <option value="6">NORTH EASTERN</option>
                              <option value="7">WESTERN</option>
                              <option value="8">RIFT VALLEY</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Kgs : </label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                              <input
                              type="text"
                              id="kgs"
                              name="kgs"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Quantity."
                              defaultValue={this.state.kgs}
                              onChange={this.updateKgs}
                              />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Packaging</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="packaging"
                              name="packaging"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Amount"
                              defaultValue={this.state.packaging}
                              onChange={this.updatePackaging}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Discount.</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="discount"
                              name="discount"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Discount."
                              defaultValue={this.state.discount}
                              onChange={this.updateDiscount}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Transport</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="transport"
                              name="transport"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Transport."
                              defaultValue={this.state.transport}
                              onChange={this.updateTransport}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Comment</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="comment"
                              name="comment"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Comment"
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Farmer Name</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <select className="form-control show-tick"
                              id="farmer_id"
                              name="farmer_id"
                          >
                            {this.state.farmerlist.map((item) => (
                              <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                                {item.name}
                              </option>
                            ))}
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>  

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Rice Type</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <select id="rice_type" name="rice_type" className="form-control show-tick">
                              <option value="1">Pishori</option>
                              <option value="2">Komboka</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Price per Kg</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="price"
                              name="price"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Price"
                              defaultValue={this.state.price}
                              onChange={this.updatePrice}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>  

                      <div className="col-lg-4"> 
                        <label htmlFor="email_address">Amount</label>
                        <div className="form-group">
                          <div className="form-line">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="amount"
                              name="amount"
                              className="form-control"
                              placeholder="Enter Amount"
                              defaultValue={this.state.amount}
                              onClick={this.updateAmount}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> 

                    
                    </div>  

                      <br />
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-success m-t-15 waves-effect "
                        disabled={this.state.btnMessage === 0 ? false : true}
                      >
                        {this.state.btnMessage === 0
                          ? "Add Order"
                          : "Adding Order Please Wait.."}
                      </button>
                      <br />
                      {this.state.errorRes === false &&
                      this.state.sendData === true ? (
                        <div className="alert alert-success">
                          <strong>Success!</strong> {this.state.errorMessage}.
                          <Link to="/orders" className="btn btn-info">View Orders</Link>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                      {this.state.errorRes === true &&
                      this.state.sendData === true ? (
                        <div className="alert alert-danger">
                          <strong>Failed!</strong>
                          {this.state.errorMessage}.
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      )}
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

Hope this helpful to anyone facing a similar problem..